# Spring Oauth2 SSO: Use Authority granted by AuthorizationServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-ldap

My setup is an AuthorizationServer where i authenticate against ldap.
When i request the user from the authorizationserver directly
he has a specifc Authority depending on the ldap group.

When i look at the Oauth2Authentication in the ResourceServer while debugging, only the userAuthentication.details.authorities has this authority. Any other authority is set to ROLE_USER.

Is ist possible to use the Authority of the user provided by the AuthorizationServer?

If i use spring.oauth2.resource.tokenInfoUri to retrieve the authority, it works. But i want to use the UserDetails provided by the AuthorizationServer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a custom UserInfoTokenServices as and provide it as i explained in an [answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092561/2576531).

In this UserInfoTokenServices I was able to extract the authorities out of the respone of the `/users`endpoint of the authorization server.

**!!UPDATE!! With Spring Boot 1.4.0 things are getting easier!**

With Spring Boot 1.4.0 a [PrincipalExtractor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/PrincipalExtractor.html) was introduced. This class should be implemented to extract a custom principal (see [Spring Boot 1.4 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#principalextractor)).

If its only about authorities you can implement [AuthoritiesExtractor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/AuthoritiesExtractor.html).