# getPrincipal() method returning username instead of UserDetails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a project using spring boot, spring security with oauth2. When I use 
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()

this method returns only username end in the examples that I see this method returns UserDetails implentation.

Follow the settings

OAuthSecurityConfig.java:

```
package br.com.altha.api.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;

import br.com.altha.api.security.CustomUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER-2)
@Import(Encoders.class)
public class OAuthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(userPasswordEncoder);
    }

}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig.java:

```
package br.com.altha.api.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;

import br.com.altha.api.security.CustomUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SECRET = "PASSWORD";

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder oauthClientPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").passwordEncoder(oauthClientPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("altha-adms")
            .secret(oauthClientPasswordEncoder.encode(SECRET))
            .scopes("write", "read")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60/*1800*/)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(1800);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(SECRET);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
}
```

ResourceServerConfig.java:

```
package br.com.altha.api.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;

import br.com.altha.api.handler.RestExceptionHandler;

@Configuration
@Import(Encoders.class)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public RestExceptionHandler handlerError() {
        return new RestExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/private/**").authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.stateless(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `getPrincipal` can return whatever it likes. So what is returned depends on the implementation of `Authentication` used and the `OAuth2Authentication` returns a `String`. So unless you reimplement the whole oauth2 part that is what you have to live with. So in short it works as it should/was designed to work.

Comment: Then, what I do to implements whole oauth2 part? Do you can show me a example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with this code:

I added a bean to UserAuthenticationConverter

```
@Bean
public UserAuthenticationConverter userAuthenticationConverter() {
    DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter defaultUserAuthenticationConverter = new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
    defaultUserAuthenticationConverter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return defaultUserAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

After this, I set this bean in the JwtAccessTokenConverter

```
@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    final JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(SECRET);
    ((DefaultAccessTokenConverter) jwtAccessTokenConverter.getAccessTokenConverter())
            .setUserTokenConverter(userAuthenticationConverter());
    return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
}
```

Comment: That's great, I'm going to be needing this when we upgrade to Spring Boot 2

Comment: thanks, this works in my resourcesserver to get the custom UserDetails Object via:


final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (authentication != null && authentication instanceof OAuth2Authentication) {
final Object principal = ((OAuth2Authentication)authentication).getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal();

Answer (score 4):

The cause would vary based on authentication/authorization technique but in my case I have 2 filters authentication/authorization the issue was passing the `username` instead of the whole user object to the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` in the authorization filter :

`return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(), .....);`

The first constructor argument is being set to `Principle` object.

So fix was to pass the whole `userDetails` object

`return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, .....);`

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot 1.5.x, you can implement a `PrincipalExtractor` and override it's `Object extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map)`. The following example component has a UserdetailsService autowired in to lookup the UserDetails object based on the username.

```
@Component
public class MyPrincipalExtractor implements PrincipalExtractor {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.principal-attribute}")
    private String principalAttribute;

    @Autowired
    public MyPrincipalExtractor(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public Object extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map) {
        if (!map.containsKey(principalAttribute)) {
            return null;
        }

        final String username = (String) map.get(principalAttribute);
        try {
            return userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            // This may be the first time this user is accessing the system, 
            // maybe you want to extract some other attributes from the map 
            // and return a different type of user object that can be used to 
            // create a new user. 
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` will contain a UserDetails object.

For a more detailed tutorial see:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-principal-authorities-extractor
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/PrincipalExtractor.html

Comment: This references Spring OAuth2 (and more specifically the Spring Boot support). This project is in maintenance mode because as of Spring Security 5 OAuth2 Is supported out-of-the-box for Spring Security. There is no guarantee that this will work with the newer Spring Security nor Spring Boot 2.0 . Also it is for Spring Boot 1.5 and not Spring Security 1.5.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes I meant to say Spring Boot 1.5.x. Will update the answer. And yes it may not work with the new Spring Security 5.

Comment: This method don't work with me, probably because I am using Spring Boot 2x

Comment: That's correct @PauloCarvalho this method only works for Spring Boot 1.5.x and Spring Security 4.2.x